# Laravel one to many mass dissociate()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Bill which has many Transaction with the relationship below:

Bill Model:

```
public function transaction()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class, 'transaction_id');
}
```

Transaction Model:

```
public function Bills()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bill::class, 'transaction_id');
}
```

In the case when the transaction fails, I need to remove all bill from that transaction and set transaction_id to null.

It can be achieved by:

```
foreach($transaction->bills as $b) {
    $b->dissociate()->save();
}
```

Is there any way to perform mass dissociate()? Maybe Something like:

```
$transaction->bills()->detach();
```

Answer (score -1):

There you go:

```
$transaction = Transaction::where('your specifications')->first();
$transaction->bills->delete();
$transaction->save()
```

**Update:**

I do not think dissociate is possible on whole collection directly.
Maybe you can create a function on the transaction model like:

```
public function dissociateBills(){

  foreach($this->bills as $b) {
    $b->dissociate()->save();
  }

$this->save();

}
```

and then call the function for a specific transaction from the controller like:

```
$transaction = Transaction::where('your specifications')->first();
$transaction->dissociateBills();
```

Comment: I guess you mean $transaction->bills()->delete();
However, this will delete the bill object as well, I just want dissociate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so basically I still have to loop through all object instead of database update. There's no implementation like DB::table ('bills')->where('transaction_id', $transaction->id)->update(['transaction_id' => null];

Comment: you can perform a db query too  but i would prefer the one i stated above , function in model file. will be clean.